# Selecting from SQL while treating carriage return and a newline as a normal space

Tags: sql

How can i write a query to select a text from a column while treating carriage return and a newline as a space, e.g.

```
  insert into [contact] (Address) 
    values ('1 2 3'),('1 2
    3'),('1
    2
    3');
```

The first entry all text is in a single line, the second entry there is a single line break, the third entry there are 3 line breaks.
I need to be able to run a statement like  `select * from  [contact] where [address] = '1 2 3'`  and be able to get all the 3 records inserted above.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method is to replace the newlines with spaces:

```
where replace([address], '
', ' ') = '1 2 3'
```